# Swap text out for other text (and execute action) onclick with JS

Tags: javascript

Currently this code hides “PLAY” when its clicked (and runs Tone.Transport.start()), but how would i make it just swap “PLAY” out for “STOP” and have “STOP” run Tone.Transport.stop() when clicked?

```
function startAndHide() {
// update();
Tone.Transport.start();
document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'none';}
```

The HTML:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 50%; text-align: center; " ><div id="start" onclick="startAndHide()">PLAY</div></div>
```

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `toggle()` method on `Tone.Transport` which stops the transport if it is started and starts it if it is stopped. Additionally you can use the `state` property on `Tone.Transport` to see if it is currently started or stopped.

To change the text on the button you can modify the `innerText` property of the DOM element.

Something similar to this:

```
function togglePlay(){
    Tone.Transport.toggle();
    const status = Tone.Transport.state; // Is either 'started', 'stopped' or 'paused'
    const element = document.getElementById("play-stop-toggle");
    if(status == "started") {
        element.innerText = "STOP";
    }
    else {
        element.innerText = "START";
    }
}
```

With the html:

```
<div id="play-stop-toggle" onclick="togglePlay()">PLAY</div>
```

Related documentation:

[https://tonejs.github.io/docs/13.8.25/Transport#state](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/13.8.25/Transport#toggle)

https://tonejs.github.io/docs/13.8.25/Transport#toggle